# Preventing the backspace key from moving to the previous page

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, keydown

```
.keydown(function(e){
        alert(e.keyCode);
...
```

This does return 8 as key of 'backspace' button. The problem though is the browsers sends be back in history!

This is the most annoying behaviour of windows browsers, I'm just trying to clear List box values with delete and backspace keys. I hate this behavior, and it's exactly the same in IE and in Chrome.

Any ideas I could make use of the backspace key?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if ( e.keyCode == 8 ) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note however that this will prevent the backspace to work in input fields. This could easily be remedied with the following:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if ( e.keyCode == 8 && e.target.tagName != 'INPUT' && e.target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, I just gotta use it for my listbox. But thanks for advice!

Comment: Oh, the second thing looks so neat. much Thanks ! Edit: The only problem is that it doesn't work - does not ignore imputs somewhy.

Comment: Yes, I will be able to set it so in 5 mins. - That's what it says

Comment: **NOTE: e.target.tagNmae returns undefined, is there any fix for this?**

Comment: @user1125062 - it's `tagName`, not `tagNmae`. I fixed it. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Use preventDefault() and as an extra guard you could use the onbeforeunload  event to warn people if they navigate away from your page